# Can't run Javascript on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom-events

I have this code here in Javascript:

```
 <label><b>Promo Code</b></label>
<input type=text value="Enter Coupon here"  name=textbox onclick="change2()">
<input type=button value="Enter" onclick="change()">

<script>
function change2() {
document.all.textbox.value=""
}
function change() {

if(document.all.textbox.value == "30%off")
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
else if(document.all.textbox.value == "50%off")
window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com/"
else
alert('Please Enter a Valid Coupon!')
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately for me I am not able to execute this in Wordpress the using html code editor. I've also used from source method:

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
    src='http://www.website.info/java.js'></script>
</form>
```

Both don't seem to work, I just put the textbox and button, but when I click I get nothing..

Comment: Also java!=javascript. Why java tag?

Comment: `document.all`? Seriously? We don't have 1990 anymore!

Comment: Wordpress does not allow any custom code to be added until some settings are disabled for accepting script from outside.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I havent seen that tag for long long time :P

Comment: I have added an answer check it out hope solves your problem. Mark me right if it does ;)

Comment: You should give a bit more information regarding what's actually happening. Is the <script>..</script> showing up as html? If so, you need to edit this somewhere other than the html editor.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually refer to this post for adding javascript to your page [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24075/insert-javascript-in-a-blog-post-or-a-new-page)

The above link carries plugins for JS inclusion.

If you want to hack the system you could look into [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)